# friend function for template class : C++

Tags: c++

I have written a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class dynArray{
    int size;
    T* ptr;
    public:
    dynArray(int n=0);
    ~dynArray();
    T& operator[] (const int index);
    friend ostream& operator<<<T>(ostream& os,const dynArray<T>& A);
    };

template<typename T> dynArray<T>::dynArray(int n):size(n){
if (size==0)
{
 cout << "Size Zero"<< endl;
 ptr=NULL;}
 else
 {
     try{
         ptr = new T[size];
         cout << "Constructor Called" << endl;
         }
     catch(bad_alloc xa)
     {
         cout << "Allocation Failure" <<endl;
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
     }
}

template<typename T> dynArray<T>::~dynArray(){
    cout << "Destructor Called for array of size : " << size << endl;
    delete[] ptr;
    }

template<typename T> T& dynArray<T>::operator[] (const int index){
    assert(index >=0 && index <size);
    return *(ptr+index);
    }

template<typename T> ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream& os,const dynArray<T>& A){
    for (int i=0; i < A.size ; i++)
    os << *(A.ptr+i) << " ";
    return os;
    }

int main()
{
    dynArray<int> array1;
    dynArray<int> array2(5);

    array2[0]=15;
    array2[3]= 45;


    cout << array2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But while compiling getting error:

```
$ g++ -Wall DynArray.cpp -o DynArray
DynArray.cpp:46: error: partial specialization `operator<< <T>' of function template
DynArray.cpp: In instantiation of `dynArray<int>':
DynArray.cpp:54:   instantiated from here
DynArray.cpp:14: error: template-id `operator<< <int>' for `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, const dynArray<int>&)' does not match any template declaration
DynArray.cpp: In function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const dynArray<T>&) [with T = int]':
DynArray.cpp:61:   instantiated from here
DynArray.cpp:8: error: `int dynArray<int>::size' is private
DynArray.cpp:47: error: within this context
DynArray.cpp:9: error: `int*dynArray<int>::ptr' is private
DynArray.cpp:48: error: within this context
```

I think my template syntax is wrong for `operator<<`. Can any one help please? Not able to figure out where is the mistake.

Comment: It's not "a" code, it's just code, or some code, or as we humans say, "a program". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class declare friend as :-

```
template<typename U>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const dynArray<U>& A);
```

And define it as :-

```
template<typename U> 
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,const dynArray<U>& A){...}
```

See [**HERE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4db6edd90344192)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `friend` a specialization of an undeclared template function. You need to declare the `operator <<` beforehand. Of course to do so, you'll need to already have a declaration of `dynArray`. This mess of forward declarations looks like this ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fdabc2af1dd8c51)):

```
template<typename T> class dynArray;

template<typename T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const dynArray<T>& A);

template<typename T>
class dynArray {
    // ...
    friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream& os, const dynArray& A);
    };
```

As [@ooga points out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567771/friend-function-for-template-class-c/21567895#comment32577260_21567895), the template parameters in the friend declaration are unnecessary; the compiler can deduce them. You could simply declare it as:

```
friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& os, const dynArray& A);
```

I personally find that syntax a bit punctuation-heavy in this instance.

Alternatively, if you find the forward declarations offensive, you could declare a separate non-template friend function for each specialization of `dynArray` by defining it in the class definition ([Coliru again](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66c637ac2c3c308f)):

```
template<typename T>
class dynArray {
    // ...
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,const dynArray& A) {
        for (int i=0; i < A.size ; i++)
        os << *(A.ptr+i) << " ";
        return os;
    }
};
```

Comment: There you go! But you probably shouldn't have `<T>` in the `friend` declaration. Just `<>` is more usual.

Comment: @ooga I thought it would be less confusing with the `T`. Any kind of `<>` with no `template` keyword is enough to get people confused in my experience - `T` or no `T`. I hope a little extra verbosity will help.

Comment: I though it wasn't allowed to have a T there. Maybe using a different letter would be better? Still, good explanation.